# RegEx - match substrings starting with a colon

Tags: php, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am struggling for hours now to find a working regex. I have this vue routes with dynamic segments and I need a regex to match those dynamic segments that starts with a colon. I know how to match substrings between two delimiters but this does not help when there is a substring to match at the end of the string. Have a look at this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2PrmDC/1).

```
companies/:company_id/users/:user_id
```

What I want to match:

- company_id
- user_id

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using this regex that uses positive look behind to ensure what matches is preceded by a colon and captures any character except `/`,

```
(?<=:)[^\/]+
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PrmDC/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it matches your example in regex101. The first capture group is your company_id and second is user_id

```
companies\/:([\w]*)\/users\/:([\w]*)
```